# 502 bad gateway on iis 8.0 intermittently using ARR

Tags: asp.net, url-rewriting, routes, iis-8

We have two application server having different url which are called as internal url and we have two more servers on where we have implemented ARR rules which are having set of rules for more 7 applications and accessed as public domain.

I am getting "502 bad gateway" again and again but after restarting iis on arr box it starts working.

Comment: What do your IIS logs say? If there is nothing there that seems relevant, can you turn up the log level, so they retain debug-level information?

Comment: I have already started that too if i checked my internal application boxes in that its working fine but if i try to make the same call from my arr boxes its giving me error of 502.3

Answer (score 0):

First, check the iis site error logs and find out what is the sub status code of the error.

To fix 502 error try below things:

1. refresh the URL in the browser.
2. clear your browser cache, cookie, and history.
3. try to Start your browser in Safe Mode.
4. restart your iis server.

**Edit:**

Please refer below article for more detail about the troubleshooting:

https://blogs.iis.net/richma/502-3-bad-gateway-the-operation-timed-out-with-iis-application-request-routing-arr

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/troubleshooting-application-request-routing/troubleshooting-502-errors-in-arr

Comment: I did everthing but its not working at all its giving me 502.3